# Chatbox with Javascript and php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, sql

I'm trying to create a chatbox using **only** JavaScript, PHP and SQL (PostgreSQL to be exact). Currently i'd have to check for new messages using an AJAX request every X seconds.

Now there are a few problems here. The biggest one may the the amount of requests being send to the server. Such an active connection might become a bandwidth killer.

Another thing is, we save these messages in our database. Always. Now, if we check for new messages, we don't want to check the entire messages table to only get our new messages. That's why I'd love to only find the new messages and send these to the client.

I've seen [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/). Seems very interesting. Unfortunately this won't be a solution right now. I kind of want to learn doing this myself, and not be dependant of third party tools.

From what I've googled, I'm going to need more than just this after all. If you have any suggestions for something to use, I'd love to hear them. But I kinda need to do this chatbox in a PHP/SQL/JS combo right now.

How would I approach something like this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're right this is tricky. PHP/SQL isn't the best toolset for it, but I understand if you're technically wedded to it. One huge problem you're going to face is that you can't index the DB effectively because of high read and high write. If you can delete old records it will keep the db queries faster... How much traffic are you expecting? What about other features? Chat rooms? Or just one big room? Will you keep messages forever?

Comment: I have no clue how big the traffic will be. It's going to be used as a side feature at some pages, to communicate with a client. That said it should be one to one only. Groups may be a nice feature, but is not a requirement. And yes, we plan to keep the messages forever.

Comment: For performance, you should also consider archiving messages older than 5-15 minutes into a separate table. Keep all the same data - just move the rows. For general purpose - you'll never use rows more than 15 minutes old anyway - so it keeps your queries quick and indexes small - and when you need to query the bigger table of older rows - it's got a lot less traffic, so that's performant too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My personal preference for chat clients in these languages involves having JavaScript save the ID of the last loaded message, and pass it back to the PHP script with every AJAX call. Then the PHP can query the database, only requesting messages with an ID higher than the given one.

When a user first loads the page, you can decide how to handle it by either loading the most recent ten messages, or messages from the last five minutes, or whatever works best for you.

I have AJAX query the server every five seconds, and even with a large number of users it's not too big of a load.

That being said, there are more efficient solutions out there that involve the server informing the clients of new messages, but they are much more complicated! If you're not willing to go with a pre-made solution, you should stick to plain AJAX polling.

Comment: Sounds great. I will try this as soon as I can. Good to hear the traffic isn't even that high, that leaves some more opportunities open. Do you, by any chance, have benchmarks of the traffic usage? Would love to see them. 
About the more complex solutions, are these also for a PHP/SQL/JS combo? Would like to know them, no matter how complicated they are :P

Comment: I'm afraid I don't, but on the rare occasions where lag does set in I have it show a neat little spinny thing telling the user there's a connection issue so they don't flip out. As for the other examples, I don't know much about them other than that they exist XD

Comment: Haha, no problem. I think I can work my way out with this. One thing, would it be useful to create a seperate conversation database, and store every conversation in their own table? I'm affraid if we only use one table, it's going to be insanely big and slow.

Comment: That really depends on how your chat program will work. For instance, mine deletes messages that are more than a minute old since it's intended to be a public chatroom that people can drop in and out of at any time. If you want more permanence, though, you may need more tables.

Comment: Well, I'd personally prefer deleting old messages too. My co-workers however think it's better to forever save them. Sounds like I will discuss this with them yet. Either way, seems like I know what to do. Thanks!

Comment: One of my sites does that, actually. Instead of just deleting them, it saves them to a text file in a log format, *then* deletes them. Thay way, daily logs can be reviewed.

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is storing messages in the DB, and using PHP to insert/retrieve messages you can make it as complex as you want with sessions and login for different users, and in the front-end you should use [jQuery ajax method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to make calls to PHP methods that answer in json or xml using [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-encode.php) so javascript can interpret this information.

So in your front-end code you could do an ajax post request when a user send a message (binding Enter key to the input) and doing a polling with a [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp),  or you could use a [push library like APE](http://www.ape-project.org/) to implement a push system this will use less the bandwidth but this will require a better server and to configure a Cron in the server so it checks everytime there's a new message.

About the DB you could determine which user sent the message using that user IP and storing it in the messages table.

Comment: A little more punctuation would be nice.

Comment: English is not my main language, but anyway hope it works for you ;).